# while generating metadata, assertion(redirection url) link is http instead of https

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, metadata, saml-2.0, spring-saml

When i generate saml metadata the assertion url happened to http instead of https.

Here is my saml configuration 
[SpringSamlConfigurations](https://pastebin.com/dT18G5A5)

You can generated sample metadata file using link below.
[link for generating metadata](https://uatcareers.timesgroup.com/talman/saml/metadata)

I went through lots of articles and similar questions on stack overflow but found nothing regarding this. So i thought i should be posting fresh questions.

Also, i am attaching properties attribute in case anyone needed

```
app.url=https://uatcareers.timesgroup.com/talman:8080
server.ssl.enabled = true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:path-to-keystore
server.ssl.key-alias = foo
server.ssl.key-store-password = foo
security.saml2.metadata-url = metadata url
```

**Please help. I have wasted 15 days on this**